# How to show $\operatorname{Gal}(\Bbb F_2(\alpha)/\Bbb F_2)$ = {$e, \sigma, \sigma^2$}

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

How to show $\operatorname{Gal}(\Bbb F_2(\alpha)/\Bbb F_2)=\{e, \sigma, \sigma^2\}$? 
$α$ is a root lying in an extension of  $\Bbb F_2$
where $\sigma(\alpha) = \alpha^2$

I have $\sigma^2(\alpha) = \alpha^4$
and $\sigma^3(\alpha) = \alpha^8$ but I'm not sure where to go further.

Also how do you prove that $\alpha^2 + \alpha$ and $ \alpha$ are conjugate over $\Bbb F_2$?

I'm not sure where to start

Comment: Hi! I think your notaion is not correct: you mean $\text{Gal}(F_2(\alpha)/F_2)$ in the first line?. Also If $\alpha$ is a root of $x^2+x+1\in F_2[x]$, then the Galois group is only $\{e,\sigma\}$ and not $\{e,\sigma,\sigma^2\}$. Do we know something more about $\alpha$?

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected. Also, $\alpha$ is a root lying in an extension of $F_2$

Comment: Well, without more informations about $\alpha$ we can not  conclude the exercise. Maybe you have thtat the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$ has degree $3$ over $F_2[x]$ (or equivalently $[F_2(\alpha):F_2]=3$)?

Comment: What Menezio said. The order of the Galois group is equal to the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. You left that part out. The Galois group has order three if and only if the minimal polynomial is either $x^3+x+1$ or $x^3+x^2+1$. Equivalently, when $F_2(\alpha)$ is known to have eight elements. The key is *which power of $\sigma$ gives the identity mapping?*